# ’Tis the season

Tags: etymology, word-usage, contractions, origin-unknown, christmas

Google has a new doodle that says *’Tis the season* when you put your cursor on it:

[image]

What is the origin of this usage? or even the contraction *’tis*?

---

**Details**:

There is a popular carol called “Deck the Halls” or “Deck the Hall” that has this line. Can we say that *’Tis the season* originates from this carol or does it go far back?

> ’Tis the season to be jolly, 
>      Fa la la la la la la la la.

[Urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tis%20the%20season) says:

> It typically refers to the time before Christmas, which can be defined as anywhere from October to December 24th.

*'Tis* is a contraction of *it is*. I think these kind of contractions are archaic but it is still used in stock uses like:

> ’Twas the night before Christmas 
>   ’Tis the season

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=%27tis) doesn’t have much to say about the origin of this contraction:

> mid-15c., contraction of it is.

Is it possible to find the origin and first usage of this contraction?

Comment: OED just refers the inquiry to the entry for *be,* where many examples include it, but nothing is said specifically *about* it.

Comment: Actually, OED gives *tys* with a proclitic pronoun as Middle English (ie from around 1175), and *tys* as a contraction as c1475.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its usage is certainly literary and  archaic. [NGram:](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%27Tis&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%27%20Tis%3B%2Cc0)  curiously shows that its usage  peaked in the 18th century, and decreased steadily  since then. Unluckily, Ngran does not offer instances of usage earlier than the 16th century.

['TIS](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%27tis): (from M-W)

> - it is,  ( contraction).
> - Origin - First Known Use: 15th century

'[TIS](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%27tis)  ( from Wiktionary)

> - (literary or archaic, also occasionally colloquial) It is.
>
>   - ’Tis the season to be jolly. — Popular Christmas song (Deck the Halls).
>   - ’Tis good ta’ ’ave ya back boy! (to have you)
>   - **1597, William Shakespeare, Romeo and Juliet, Act 3, Scene 1:**
>       Mercutio [wounded]: "No, 'tis not so deep as a well, nor so wide as a church-door; but 'tis enough, 'twill serve: ask for me to-morrow, and you shall find me a grave man."
>   - 1844, Charles Dickens, The Chimes, Chapter III:
>       It looks well in a picter, I've heerd say; but there an't weather in picters, and maybe 'tis fitter for that, than for a place to live in.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%27Tis%2C%27twas%2C%27twere&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%27%20Tis%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%27%20tis%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27%20Tis%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%27%20twas%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%27%20twas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27%20Twas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%27%20twere%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%27%20twere%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27%20Twere%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%27%20TWERE%3B%2Cc0) 'tis, 'twere, 'twas.

[Literary quotations with 'tis](http://www.finedictionary.com/%27Tis.html):

George Eliot:

> - “'Tis God gives skill, but not without men's hand: He could not make Antonio Stradivarius's violins without Antonio.”

William Shakespeare:

> - “If it were done when 'tis done, then t'were well it were done quickly.”

George Washington:

> - “'Tis our true policy to steer clear of permanent alliances with any portion of the foreign world.”

Robert Browning:

> - “'Tis not what man does which exalts him, but what man Would do!”

Emily Dickinson:

> - “Anger as soon as fed is dead; 'Tis starving makes it fat.”